# google analytics api change web property according to account

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

i am beginner in Google Analytic's API's. i have more then 1 account in Analytic's and each account have different web properties. now what i am trying to do is to change the web property list according to the account. so i have 1 dropdown which displays accounts list and second dropdown which displays web properties but on change of account from dropdown list it should change web properties and i can't figure out how i can do it

code:

```
    try {
    global $_params, $output_title, $output_body;
    $output_title = 'Adwords';
    $output_nav = '<li><a href="'.$scriptUri.'?logout">Logout</a></li>'."\n";
    $output_body = '<h1>Google Adwords Access demo</h1>
                    <p>The following domains are in your Google Adwords account</p><select>';
                    $accountToPropertyMap = array();            
    $accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts("~all");
  foreach($accounts['items'] as $item) {
  $id = $item->getId();
 $output_body .= sprintf('<option value="">%1$s</option>', $item['name']);
    }
    $output_body .= '</select>';

$output_prop ='<h1>web properties</h1><select>';
$service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($id);
    $accountToPropertyMap = $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($id);
    foreach($webproperties['items'] as $item) {
        $output_prop .= sprintf('<option>%1$s</option>', $item['name']);
    }
    $output_prop .= '</select>';
    include("output.php");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('<html><body><h1>An error occured: ' . $e->getMessage()."\n </h1></body></html>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `listManagementWebproperties("~all")` will return [ALL the accounts that user has access to](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/webproperties/list#accountId).

If you want to display only the web properties for the selected account you need to pass that account's ID into `listManagementWebproperties(accountid).`

A way to do this in preprocessing is to do this call for each account and save these groups of properties separately and then display them as needed.

You can select an account and use Account ID = {$account->getId()} to get the id and then put that into the call for the properties.

Example Snippet:

```
$accountToPropertyMap = array();
$accounts = $service->management_accounts->listManagementAccounts("~all");
foreach($accounts as $account){
    $id = $account->getId();
    $service->management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($id)
    $accountToPropertyMap[$id] = management_webproperties->listManagementWebproperties($id);
}
```

Then retrieve the properties from the array. You can use a more relevant key than the id for your application depending on your needs.

Comment: i think there should be some dynamic way to do it. the way you told me is only usable for one account. so what if some one else try to use my app?? i hope you understand my point here

Comment: You are getting the account information based on the client correct? Don't hardcode the accountIds, get them from the accounts you queried. Select an account and use `Account ID   = {$account->getId()}` to get the id. Then put that into the call for the properties.

Comment: well i tried this before what you suggested now. but unfortunately i got no results may be i was doing something wrong. so please can give an example of your suggestion with  my code given above.

Comment: Added example. If you still have issues provide your version of the code that got no results

Comment: thanks a lot for your concern and your help i will try your code and will get back to you :)

Comment: i have updated my question with my code which i am trying so when i execute it it give me blank page and display nothing. actually i am trying to display the accounts and webproperties in dropdownlist

Comment: I addressed your problem with the analytics api, your issue seems to be with your php code which is beyond this question. If you need php help, I recommend you read the documenation and if needed, open another question. One problem I see is your variables are improperly scoped, you are referencing `$id` outside the loop it is declared in.